# How to check if there is multiple similar MAX value in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, double

I have code which consists of Array in doubles, but right now I am trying to check how to detect if there is two similar MAX in the array. The number MAX that I have set is 100. So if there is two or more 100, I would like to display output: Multiple MAX value. Hence I thought of using IF-ELSE, but I am not sure on how to check for Multiple MAX value.

```
    This is my code:

    double num1 = 100;
    double num2 = 100;
    double num3 = 70;
    double num4 = 65;

    double[] array1 = { num1, num2, num3, num4 };

    double text = array1.Max();

    if()
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Comment: Remember that comparing doubles/floats is dangerous business and you should consider using some 'close enough' system. Read http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Count` extension method, Try this code:

```
if(array1.Count(x=>x == text) > 1){
  //...
} else {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count=0;
    bool maxreached=false;
    for(int i=0;i<array1.Length;i++)
    {
       if(array1[i]==text)
       count++;
       if(count>1)
       {
          maxreached=true;
          break;
       }
    }   

if(maxreached)
Console.WriteLine("Max value = "+ text +" found multiple times");
```

Comment: Thanks if I also want to display that array number, how can I do it?

Comment: you mean array number or maxcount? if number ,which array number ?

Comment: @user2901798: if you want to print max value see my edited answer.